# How to animate the pendulum of a clock where the pendulum starts in the 6 o'clock position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I try to animate the motion of a pendulum which is starting at the 6 o'clock position, then swings a few times and then stops again in the 6 o'clock position.

I already know how to change the anchor point of a layer and how to rotate it.

I have a method to rotate a layer.

```
- (void)spinLayer:(CALayer *)inLayer duration:(CFTimeInterval)inDuration direction:(int)direction forPartsOfPi:(float) degrees withReverse:(bool) reverse andRepeatCount:(float) repeatCount;
```

I thought it might be best to split the movement of the pendulum in 3 "swings" The first swing is from the starting position to lets say 9 o'clock position. So this is the first time i call the Method.

```
[self spinLayer:layer duration:0.4 direction:SPIN_CLOCK_WISE forPartsOfPi:M_PI/2 withReverse:NO andRepeatCount:0];
```

Then, in the animationDidFinish Delegate i call the method once again to let it do the several swings.
For the rotation of the Pendulum is now double the length of the first swing i call:

```
[self spinLayer:layer duration:0.8 direction:SPIN_COUNTERCLOCK_WISE forPartsOfPi:M_PI withReverse:YES andRepeatCount:4];
```

after that i want the pendulum to return to 6 o'clock position so i call:

```
[self spinLayer:layer duration:0.4 direction:SPIN_COUNTERCLOCK_WISE forPartsOfPi:M_PI/2 withReverse:NO andRepeatCount:0];
```

Here is the implementation of my Method:

```
- (void)spinLayer:(CALayer *)inLayer duration:(CFTimeInterval)inDuration direction:(int)direction forPartsOfPi:(float) degrees withReverse:(bool) reverse andRepeatCount:(float) repeatCount
{


   CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;

    // Rotate about the z axis
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

    // Rotate 180 degress, in direction specified
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: degrees * direction];

    // Perform the rotation over this many seconds
    rotationAnimation.duration = inDuration;

    rotationAnimation.autoreverses = reverse;

    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount;
    rotationAnimation.delegate  = self;

    // Set the pacing of the animation
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    // Add animation to the layer and make it so
    [inLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

So the problem is, that the second swing doesn't start at the end of the first swing but on the 6 o'clock position.

Can anybody set me straight how to do this?

Thx in advance

Mav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation starts from the value of the *model layer*'s property.  The animation only affects the *presentation layer*.  So after the first animation is done, the model layer still points in the 6 o'clock orientation.

What you should do is in your `spinLayer` method, set the layer's transform to the final orientation transform:

```
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Oops you're right.  By the way, the transform should be set after the animation starts, or maybe when the animation ends.

Comment: I added the following line to my `spinLayer`but to no avail:
`inLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI * direction / 180, 0, 0, 1);`
The result is the same. The Pendulum starts each swing from the 6 o'clock position. :(
I added it directly after adding the animation to the layer.

Comment: I noticed you multiplied by `M_PI` there, but you didn't when setting `rotationAnimation.toValue`.  Isn't the value already in radians?

Comment: The value i passed is only a fraction of M_PI. But this confuses me all the time. So if i pass a fraction of M_PI as a parameter is this in degrees or in radians then?
Well anyway. I tried both ways and none worked :(

Comment: late but not too late to accept. :) found the error in my code. Your solution was correct. thx :)